# Incredibuild not working

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, multiprocessing

I am having Incredibuild for building Visual Studio Project but its not working stating warning message ,

> Warning: FORCE_NO_INCREDIBUILD is set. Build process will be time consuming unless you remove it.

I googled FORCE_NO_INCREDIBUILD but not getting a single result.

Please get me rid of that.

Thanks,
Amit.

Comment: You probably want to accept a few answers to other questions before this.

Answer (score 0):

FORCE_NO_INCREDIBUILD is a custom variable which is not being related to Visual Studio and Incredibuild at all.

I commented out with it form batch script. Now incredibuild is working....:)

Thanks Amit